# Call css animation in HTML

Tags: html, css

Hi I was just wondering how do you call a css animation in a HTML tag like a button or something like this

CSS:

```
#first-child {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 0%;
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-left: 550px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    -webkit-animation: myfirst 1s;
    -moz-animation: myfirst 1s;
    animation: myfirst 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
    0% {background: white;}
   20% {background: white;}
   40% {background: white;}
   60% {background: white;}
   80% {background: white;}
  100% {background: red;}
}

@keyframes myfirst {
   0% {background: white;}
  20% {background: white;}
  40% {background: white;}
  60% {background: white;}
  80% {background: white;}
 100% {background: red;}
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="first-child"></div>
<button onclick="call animation"></button>
```

I have already tried to call myfirst but it dosen't work,, Thanks in advance, peace !

Comment: Use javascript to add a specific class which uses the animation.

Comment: you'll need to use jquery to add a class to the div. Which will hold the animation

Comment: Can someone post a code ? :p

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    var ANIMATE = $('#first-child').addClass('animation');
    setTimeout(function () {
    ANIMATE.removeClass('animation');
    }, 1500);
});
```

```css
body {
   background: #aaa;
}
#first-child {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 0%;
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-left: 550px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
    0% {background: white;}
   20% {background: white;}
   40% {background: white;}
   60% {background: white;}
   80% {background: white;}
  100% {background: red;}
}

@keyframes myfirst {
   0% {background: white;}
  20% {background: white;}
  40% {background: white;}
  60% {background: white;}
  80% {background: white;}
 100% {background: red;}
}
.animation {
    -webkit-animation: myfirst 1s;
    -moz-animation: myfirst 1s;
    animation: myfirst 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first-child"></div>
<button>Add Animation</button>
```

Comment: Is it possible to make it blink every time you click on the button ?

Comment: In order to mimic "blink" you have to develop animation completing it at 50% of time, and then apply reverse animation for the remain 50% in order to have final status equal to start one. In this way, making it cyclical, it mimic an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks, but what I want to know is how you can call the animation onclick in the button tag,, you know by name or something